# I have an error in Json or guzzle in my laravel project. Can someone help me?

Tags: json, laravel, guzzle

Laravel is accusing that the error is on line 24. I tried some alternatives that I found on the internet but nothing worked. Can someone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg3MM.png)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Guzzle for decode. you can simply use `json_decode`

```
$itemdata = $res->getBody()->getContents();
$items = json_decode($itemdata);
```